# "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

Tags: composer

cPanel PHP Version: 7.3

Drupal 8.8

I am trying to install *upgrade_status* module via composer for the first time in a shared hosting server but I am unable to do that. Below shows the error that I get.

```
lz@lz [~/public_html]$ composer require 'drupal/upgrade_status:^3.18'
```

Error

```
The "composer/installers" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.2.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
The "drupal/core-composer-scaffold" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.0.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.2.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
The "drupal/core-project-message" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.1") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.2.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
The "drupal/core-vendor-hardening" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.1") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.2.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
./composer.json has been updated
The "composer/installers" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.2.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
The "drupal/core-composer-scaffold" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.0.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.2.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
The "drupal/core-project-message" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.1") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.2.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
The "drupal/core-vendor-hardening" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.1") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.2.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
Running composer update drupal/upgrade_status
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - mglaman/phpstan-drupal[1.0.0, ..., 1.1.4] require php ^7.1 || ^8.0 -> your php version (7.0.8; overridden via config.platform, actual: 7.3.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mglaman/phpstan-drupal[1.1.5, ..., 1.1.26] require php ^7.4 || ^8.0 -> your php version (7.0.8; overridden via config.platform, actual: 7.3.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - drupal/upgrade_status 3.18.0 requires mglaman/phpstan-drupal ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mglaman/phpstan-drupal[1.0.0, ..., 1.1.26].
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/upgrade_status ^3.18 -> satisfiable by drupal/upgrade_status[3.18.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

[image]
[image]
How can I install the module via the composer?

Comment: In future, provide the composer.json file when asking Composer questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Composer is too *new* for the old plugins specified and the config.platform configured PHP version in composer.json is older than the actual 7.3 version. This is what the output says.